# How can I include an OnPlatform in a style resource?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="pointButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="#999999"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#AAAAAA" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="StartAndExpand" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10" />
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="40" />
</Style>
```

I would like to include this. Is it possible?

```xml
<Button.FontSize>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="25" Android="20" />
</Button.FontSize>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define every property as OnPlatform

```xml
<OnPlatform x:Key="MyFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="14" Android="14" WinPhone="14" />
```

and refer it in yout button style like

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource MyFontSize}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 30):

With the new Xamarin **OnPlatform** [specification](https://montemagno.com/important-onplatform-changes-xamarin-forms/) is possible to define the platform styles directly in the **style** tag:

```xml
<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="Android">40</On>
            <On Platform="iOS">10</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```